# How to assing new mouse event on node without overriding those set earlier?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Example:

```
domNode.onmouseover = function() {
  this.innerHTML = "The mighty mouse is over me!"
}
domNode.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

In this example the text won't change, but the thing is also that I don't always know what was assigned before, so is there a way to tell to js: Run everything that was eventually assigned without knowing what was that and then run my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this by passing the current event handler to the new handler:

```
domNode.onmouseover = function()
{
    console.log('first handler');
}
domNode.onmouseover = (function (current)
{
    return function()
    {
        current();//call handler that was set when this handler was created
        console.log('new handler');
    };
})(domNode.onmouseover);//pass reference to current handler
```

[**See this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymxK9/), to see it in action
You can keep on doing this as much as you want/need:

```
domNode.onmouseover = function()
{
    console.log('first handler');
}
domNode.onmouseover = (function (current)
{
    return function()
    {
        current();
        console.log('second handler');
    };
})(domNode.onmouseover);
domNode.onmouseover = (function (current)
{
    return function()
    {
        current();
        console.log('third handler');
    };
})(domNode.onmouseover);
```

This will log:

```
first handler
second handler
third handler
```

That's all there is to it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, place it in a document.ready. (not sure if you done that)
If you want 2 actions for one action place it in once function.

You can also create 2 functions and call them in your mouseover.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   domNode.onmouseover = function() {
     this.innerHTML = "The mighty mouse is over me!"
     this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
   }
});
```

Comment: There is no jQuery tag here, and this doesn't answer the question at all, the question was how a _second_ handler can be bound, without unsetting the first handler.

Comment: just a side-note: wrapping everything in a `.ready` callback function isn't standard JS practice, in fact, in some cases, you want your code to run as soon as possible, even before the DOM is fully loaded